# How to allow adding rows after blocking some columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this sheet for company workers to see their tasks and execute them. Some columns are allowed to edit, like when the activity started and when its finished.

The problem with it is, because some columns are blocked for control reasons, the workers can't individualy add new rows for new tasks. Only the proprietary and a worker named Julius can add new rows. Julius can because he has permission to edit the protected columns.

I've tested removing the Julius permission to edit protected colmuns and instantly becames unable to add new rows.

The button code i use to create new rows is irrelevant, but i'm pasting a part of it bellow:

```
function Inserirnovalinha() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  /** nova linha */
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
```

Is there a way to allow the rest of the workers to add new rows but keeping the blocked columns?

Note: I use a button with script to add new rows. This happens because the script adds a few texts that are needed when a new row is created.